# Asp.net Routing not works when hosted on root

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, asp.net-routing

I have used Asp.net 4.0 Routing techniques to achieve friendly urls. I have used following code in global.asax..

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

    string connectionstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Sch_Sp_GetRegisterRoutes", sqlCon);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlCon.Close();

    }
    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                routes.MapPageRoute(dr["Menuname"].ToString().Replace(" ",string.Empty),
              dr["URL"].ToString(),
               "~/" + dr["Pagename"].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {

            }

        }
    }


}
```

my url in database is like About-Us and Pagename is like MyFolder/Aboutus.aspx. In my local machine it worked but when I deploy it on my server(iis 7 version and windows server 2008) it shows error '
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable' 
I have call it as resolveUrl("~/About-Us").
Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding few lines of code in web.config , it wil worked for me..

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
        <remove name="Session"/>
        <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition=""/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
       preCondition="integratedMode"
       verb="*"
       path="UrlRouting.axd"
       type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>

    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You don't need (or want) runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"